# Fab 40 Test-SPContentDatabase Upgrade Missing Assembly Error

Tags: upgrade, fab-40

I'm getting a Fab 40 related MissingAssembly error in the output of Test-SPContentDatabase. The strange part is that the version number of the assembly referenced in the output is incorrect.

> Category        : MissingAssembly
>   Error           : True
>   UpgradeBlocking : False
>   Message         : Assembly [**KnowledgeBaseEventHandler**, **Version=14.0.0.0**, Cultur
>                    e=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c] is referenced in 
>                    the database [SAMPLE], but is not installed on t
>                    he current farm. Please install any feature/solution which co
>                    ntains this assembly.
>   Remedy          : One or more assemblies are referenced in the database [SAMPLE], but are not installed on the current farm. Pl
>                    ease install any feature or solution which contains these ass
>                    emblies.

The KnowledgeBaseEventHandler assembly should have a version of 12.0.0.0. In fact I can see that the KnowledgeBaseEventHandler is in the GAC with a version of 12.0.0.0.

I'm also getting similar missing assembly errors for DocumentReviewEventHandler, ResourceEventHandler, and ReservationEventHandler. Again these assemblies are also already in the GAC at version 12.

I've installed these same Fab 40 templates (WSP) in another lab environment and didn't see any of these issues. I know there are other concerns about Fab 40 in 2010, I'm just trying to track down this problem right now.

Why is this error reported? What's with the wrong version number?

Answer (score 2):

What you are actually doing with Test-SPcontentDatabase is testing it against the 2010 version, which would mean that the version of the assembly should be 14.0.0.0 in the new version. It is telling you this version does not exist. This error is correct, and you will not be able to directly upgrade this content in this manner. The Fab 40 templates (well most of them) do not upgrade. I think I have heard of a couple of instances where an upgrade of a specific type was successful, but I would not recommend it. What you will end up doing with sites that have used the fab 40 in production is either using a tool to migrate the data or manually migrating the data into 2010. Good luck!